# about remove/replace struct

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a C language code that uses struct, including functions and function calls that initialize the structure. Now I want to remove the use of structs. Due to problems with code execution, and a lot of code and complicated structs, I can't change these manually. Functions and structures, so I have to find an automated method. The following code is a simple example. 
Is there any better way or idea?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct A add(int x, int y)
{
  struct A t;
  t.a = x + y;
  return t;
}

int main()
{
  struct A t = add(3, 4);
  printf("t.a = %ld\n", t.a);
  return 0;
}
```

To:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int A_a = 3;
  int A_b = 4;
  int A_a_b = A_a + A_b;
  printf("%d\n", A_a_b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might need to write your own script to do this.  But given the level of understanding it will need, it might not be easy.  Some level of parsing seems to be needed.

Comment: Unless your code is completely trivial, this will be very hard. And looks like the opposite of what you should be doing (e.g. if the code is complex, define better abstractions, rather than tearing everything down to glorified assembly.)

Comment: If a struct is complicating your code, then your design must be wrong. The idea of a structure or objects is to simplify the process. So rather than finding a way around structs, learn to properly use structs.

Comment: yes, the idea of a structure or objects is to simplify the process.But there are all other problems here. In fact, I ended up not doing this in the C language,but in the shader(glsl). At present, the initialization of the structure will have some problems on the Qualcomm processor platform,so I have to avoid using the structure in the program. I want to make it easier for more people to understand my problem, so I used the c language as an example.If you are interested, here are the shader test code for this issue.Check at https://github.com/verybigzhouhai/struct-init-test-on-qualcomm-platform

Comment: What you need is a tool designed to manipulate source code.   These are pretty rare although some exist for C.  I doubt anything exists for a shader langauge so you'll need to build a custom tool.    THis is likely to take awhile and some skill, so might not be worth the effort.   But if you insist  you might consider our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit as a foundation.  www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried antlr?

I guess you'd like refactor the code to below.

## include

```
/*
struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
*/

/*
struct A add(int x, int y)
{
  struct A t;
  t.a = x + y;
  return t;
}
*/

int main()
{
/*
  struct A t = add(3, 4);
*/  
  int A0_t_a; //t.a
  int A0_t_b; //t.b
  {
    //add(3, 4)
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;

    //struct A t;
    int A1_t_a;
    int A1_t_b;

    //t.a = x + y
    A1_t_a = x + y;

    //return t
    A0_t_a = A1_t_a;
    A0_t_b = A1_t_b;
  }

/*
  printf("t.a = %ld\n", t.a);
*/
  printf("t.a = %ld\n", A0_t_a);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.